# Is there an R function to split an interval into two intervals when it doesn't fit into a single interval?

Tags: r

I have a single data frame that I merged from two data frames with foverlaps. The block intervals were placed in the window intervals, but I have many cases in which the block interval doesn't fully fit into the window interval, such as row 4. I was wondering if there is a R function that would split this the block interval to fit into corresponding window intervals? For example, if I have window_start=0, window_end=100, block_start_1=56, block_end_1=139, I would want to split this into the following two windows like so: window_start=0, window_end=100, block_start_1=56, block_end_1=100 and window_start=100, window_end=200, block_start_1=100, block_end_1=139. A more detailed example below.

Data frame:

```
   window_start_1 window_end_1 block_start_1 block_end_1
 1:              0       100000          5361       70817
 2:              0       100000         71240       94801
 3:              0       100000         95115       95965
 4:             NA           NA         96099      181692
 5:             NA           NA        182089      202832
 6:         200000       300000        203053      203513
 7:         200000       300000        203957      252559
 8:         200000       300000        255798      281602
 9:         200000       300000        282652      285340
10:         200000       300000        285821      286233
11:         200000       300000        286452      286747
12:             NA           NA        287001      307802
13:         300000       400000        308305      318149
14:         300000       400000        319175      323252
15:         300000       400000        323461      333007
```

Desired output:

```
   window_start_1 window_end_1 block_start_1 block_end_1
 1:              0       100000          5361       70817
 2:              0       100000         71240       94801
 3:              0       100000         95115       95965
 4:              0       100000         96099      100000
 5:         100000       200000        100000      181692 
 6:         100000       200000        182089      200000
 7:         200000       300000        200000      202832
 8:         200000       300000        203053      203513
 9:         200000       300000        203957      252559
10:         200000       300000        255798      281602
11:         200000       300000        282652      285340
12:         200000       300000        285821      286233
13:         200000       300000        286452      286747
14:         200000       300000        287001      300000
15:         300000       400000        300000      307802
16:         300000       400000        308305      318149
17:         300000       400000        319175      323252
18:         300000       400000        323461      333007
```

I started writing a function but wanted to know if there is anything out there already, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There may well be an existing function somewhere, but it's straightforward enough to just write your own. Just pass the start and stop vectors, and a vector of the breaks between windows.

```r
f <- function(start, stop, breaks) {
  do.call("rbind", Map(function(start, stop) {
    floor <- breaks[max(which(breaks < start))]
    ceiling <- breaks[min(which(breaks > stop))]
    spans <- breaks[breaks < stop & breaks > start]
    if(length(spans) == 0) {
      return(t(c(floor, ceiling, start, stop)))
    }
    breaks <- c(floor, spans, ceiling)
    cbind(head(breaks, -1), 
          tail(breaks, -1),
          c(start, head(tail(breaks, -1), -1)),
          c(head(tail(breaks, -1), -1), stop))
  }, start, stop)) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(c("window_start_1", "window_end_1", "block_start_1", "block_end_1"))
}
```

Testing, we have:

```r
f(df$block_start_1, df$block_end_1, seq(0, 1e6, 1e5))
#>    window_start_1 window_end_1 block_start_1 block_end_1
#> 1               0       100000          5361       70817
#> 2               0       100000         71240       94801
#> 3               0       100000         95115       95965
#> 4               0       100000         96099      100000
#> 5          100000       200000        100000      181692
#> 6          100000       200000        182089      200000
#> 7          200000       300000        200000      202832
#> 8          200000       300000        203053      203513
#> 9          200000       300000        203957      252559
#> 10         200000       300000        255798      281602
#> 11         200000       300000        282652      285340
#> 12         200000       300000        285821      286233
#> 13         200000       300000        286452      286747
#> 14         200000       300000        287001      300000
#> 15         300000       400000        300000      307802
#> 16         300000       400000        308305      318149
#> 17         300000       400000        319175      323252
#> 18         300000       400000        323461      333007
```

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(window_start_1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 200000L, 
200000L, 200000L, 200000L, 200000L, 200000L, NA, 300000L, 300000L, 
300000L), window_end_1 = c(100000L, 100000L, 100000L, NA, NA, 
300000L, 300000L, 300000L, 300000L, 300000L, 300000L, NA, 400000L, 
400000L, 400000L), block_start_1 = c(5361L, 71240L, 95115L, 96099L, 
182089L, 203053L, 203957L, 255798L, 282652L, 285821L, 286452L, 
287001L, 308305L, 319175L, 323461L), block_end_1 = c(70817L, 
94801L, 95965L, 181692L, 202832L, 203513L, 252559L, 281602L, 
285340L, 286233L, 286747L, 307802L, 318149L, 323252L, 333007L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```